# Why is viewDidLayoutSubviews called multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm developing iOS Universal App with Swift, using auto layout and support only portrait.

I found `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` called multiple times. Instead, `viewDidLoad` is only called once on starting up MyApp's `UIViewController`.

Why is `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called multiple times? Will constraints on each `UIView` (`UIButtons`,`UITextFields`, etc..) be performed in order?

Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`LoadView` is only called once: when the view needs to be loaded.

`LayoutSubviews`, however, is called once per run loop on any view that has had `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect` called on it - this includes whenever a subview has been added to the view, scrolling, resizing, etc.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on what is setNeedsLayout & setNeedsDisplayInRect? I couldn't understand the linked page..

Comment: Check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13542580) for a good explanation about `setNeedsLayout`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do and this has served me well - is to get in to the habit of adding a log or print statement to methods of which you are unsure

I use this ->

```
print("Hello From \(NSStringFromSelector(#function))")
```

or this if inside a View Subclass

```
Swift.print("Hello From \(NSStringFromSelector(#function))")
```

It will print the method when it is being called.