# viewWillLayoutSubviews called many times

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am seeing viewWillLayoutSubviews called repeatedly every time I update title text of UIButton, which is in a subview. I am not sure why, because there is no bounds change or change in view position. Is viewWillLayoutSubviews really called when subview of a subview gets refreshed?

```
    button?.setTitle(text, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    button?.setTitle(text, for: UIControl.State.selected)
```

Comment: Could you add a code sample? It's almost 100% caused by something you are doing in that method, or another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why viewdidlayoutsubviews call multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014360/why-viewdidlayoutsubviews-call-multiple-times)

Comment: Well only when I move phone around (without rotating) it happens. The code is very long, but I need tips to catch the culprit.

Comment: @simonthumper I provided more info in the question.

Comment: That's really still not enough detail I'm afraid! We really need code examples @DeepakSharma

Comment: That means I need to generate a minimal code sample, otherwise it is more than 3000 lines of code.

Comment: @simonthumper I updated the question with details.