# Frame of view is not updated in AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

Getting the updated frame with AutoLayouts it is a problem, that I know and been through it's solutions. All [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446920/how-can-i-get-a-views-current-width-and-height-when-using-autolayout-constraint) are very much efficient but my problem has a limp.

Things I have done :

I have a UIView that I needed to change size of it at demand so I supplied a key `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as `YES`. Because I have created constraints for this UIView and constraints were not letting me change/reflect the frame. Now I am successfully able to change the frame but new problem is `view` is not giving rendered cordinates [origin(x,y)]. Origin values are not updated.

If I remove `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` then it works. But I need it.

I have tried other solutions like updating the UI at call using - `[view setNeedsLayout] and [view layoutIfNeeded]` or delaying the retrieval of rendered frames using `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` But nothing works.

Comment: Have you added your view and it's constraints in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

if you have some constraints, that doesn't let you change coordinates, then you should change this constraints, but not frame... just create outlets for this constraints, change `constant` property and use `layoutIfNeeded` method

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using auto-layout you need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO

But back to your question.  One thing you could do, is to use KVO (key-value observer) to notify you when the bounds of the view change.  For example:

`[self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];`

Then, create an observer method, such as:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

  CGRect frame  = self.view.frame;

}
```

From frame you should be able to get width and height.  Note, that this method may be called multiple times..