# Get actual view size after setting constraints

Tags: ios, swift, view, size

How do I get the actual view size? Right now I am getting it from `gameView.frame.size`. It does give me the right values that I set, but it doesn't give me the actual size.

For example, in my storyboard I have an iPhone 11 and I draw a frame of width:`375` and height:`375` with constraints.

And now I simulate an iPad and the frame indeed does have the right constraints, but it is still giving me back the values 375-375 but that isn't the actual size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a view's current width and height when using autolayout constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446920/how-can-i-get-a-views-current-width-and-height-when-using-autolayout-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options; based on your use case:

1. Get your frame by using:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     //print(self.view.frame)
   }
   ```
2. get your updated frame values in `viewDidAppear`
3. get your updated frame values in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But be careful this is called multiple times.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446920/how-can-i-get-a-views-current-width-and-height-when-using-autolayout-constraint for another solution.